# Should the "embedded-code" tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Most of my participation is in [embedded](/questions/tagged/embedded), which is a relatively small community. I recently stumbled across [embedded-code](/questions/tagged/embedded-code). It had only 30 questions, 1 follower, and no wiki; its usage is inconsistent at best:

1. Using it instead of the more proper (and more followed) tag for embedded systems [embedded](/questions/tagged/embedded)
2. Tagging both [embedded](/questions/tagged/embedded) and [embedded-code](/questions/tagged/embedded-code)
3. Random tagging of anything relating to somehow embedding something (Is [embed](/questions/tagged/embed) a better fit?)

As this was only 30 tags, I went in and retagged all cases of condition 1, and have now removed the extra tags from those in the 2nd category.

For the 23 questions left in category 3, the tag doesn't seem to add any value at all.

It seems to me that this tag should be removed, as [embed](/questions/tagged/embed) and [embedded](/questions/tagged/embedded) already meet the need.

Comment: [Embedded devices/systems](https://www.google.com/#q=embedded+device) are different than embedded code.  You might want to be able to clarify that distinction in the tags.

Comment: Embedded systems are not embedded code, I agree.  However, given that in all cases the embedded code tag is about code running on an embedded system, or the random "embedding something", it doesn't seem like the tag is working.  Also considering that 23 questions have "embedded-code" while there are 3k for embedded and 2k for embed.  It doesn't seem like there is any semantic content for embedded code that we could tell people when to use it.

Comment: @Kiamlaluno Thank you for the tag edits, I didn't know the markup for it.

Comment: If you only edit the tags, your edit should go through (or at least it'll be submitted, unfortunately some SO reviewers have now taken to rejecting all tag edits as too minor). But if you edit the body, you must change at least 6 characters, even if you also changed the tags, which is a little stupid.

Comment: How do you find life in the [tag:embedded] tag? In the past I found it too full of questions about embedding software A and software B to bother. There is a [proposal for a site about embedded programming](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50195/embedded-programming-and-design?referrer=2lF5gAel4peFRGSmvGLajg2) which would combine the programming aspects of embedded devices with some hardware aspects as well as aspects not covered by any existing site such as integration issues.

Comment: @Gillies It's a nice diversion...  Every few days I take a few minutes to retag incorrectly tagged items, so it's a fairly clean with just embedded systems stuff.  I prefer to see embedded stuff on SO as I prefer to focus on algorithms and software design concepts as opposed trying to solve people's port pin problems, but I'll check out the Area 51 link...